# Not able to start docker daemon in Debian OS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to install docker in Debian OS. Successfully installed it but I am not able to PULL/PUSH docker images.

I am getting the below error.

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

When I am checking the daemon logs I am seeing this error.

```
error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting... module=grpc
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
(exit status 3)
```

I started the docker manually but still, it's going to stop state automatically.
I created a separate user and added it to the docker group, even though I tried to run with the root user also still saw the same error.

````
 * Starting Docker docker                                                                                                                                           [ OK ]
root@:/etc# service docker status
 * Docker is not running```

How can i start the docker ?
````

Answer (score 0):

Check the your docker installed path having right permission to your user or not.

Checkout this link: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/